# Update values in a pandas dataframe based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas

Hello trying to update values in a dataframe based on multiple conditions.  Where there is category that is Gas/Fuel less than $30 I want to change the category to food.

```
data.loc[60:65,['Category','Debit']]

    Category    Debit
60  Groceries   38.18
61  Gas/Fuel    7.30
62  Fast Food   9.18
63  Pharmacy    7.03
64  Gas/Fuel    3.16
65  Pharmacy    9.40

for index, row in data.iterrows():
    if row[3] == 'Gas/Fuel' and row[4] < 30:
        row[3]='Fast Food'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
c = df['Category'].eq('Gas/Fuel') & df['Debit'].lt(30)
df.loc[c,'Category']='Food'
```

or

```
df['Category'] = df['Category'].mask(c,'Food')
#df['Category'] = df['Category'].where(~c,'Food')
```